# React Hook "useState" is called in function "app" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use react hooks for a simple problem

```
const [personState,setPersonState] = useState({ DefinedObject });
```

with following dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0"
}
```

but I'm still getting the following error:

> ./src/App.js
>
> Line 7:
>   React Hook "useState" is called in function
>   "app" which is neither a React function component or a custom React
>   Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
>
> Line 39:
>   'state' is not defined
>   no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Component code is below:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'; 
import './App.css'; 
import Person from './Person/Person'; 

const app = props => { 
    const [personState, setPersonSate] = useState({ person:[ {name:'bishnu',age:'32'}, {name:'rasmi',age:'27'}, {name:'fretbox',age:'4'} ], }); 
    return (
        <div className="App"> 
            <h2>This is react</h2> 
            <Person name={personState.person[1].name} age="27"></Person>
            <Person name={personState.person[2].name} age="4"></Person> 
        </div> ); 
    };
    export default app;
```

Person component

```
import React from 'react'; 

const person = props => { 
    return( 
        <div>
            <h3>i am {props.name}</h3>
            <p>i am {props.age} years old</p>
            <p>{props.children}</p>
        </div> 
    )
};

export default person;
```

Comment: Can you share your component code?

Comment: import React,{useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person';
const app= props => {

  const [personState,setPersonSate]=  useState({
    person:[
      {name:'bishnu',age:'32'},
      {name:'rasmi',age:'27'},
      {name:'fretbox',age:'4'}      
    ],
  }); 
  return (
          <div className="App">
          <h2>This is react</h2>         
          <Person name={personState.person[1].name}  age="27"></Person>
          <Person name={personState.person[2].name}  age="4"></Person>
          </div>
      );
};export default app;

Comment: Person Component      :-                                                                                                                      import React from 'react';

const person=(props)=>{
    return(
        <div>
            <h3>i am {props.name}</h3>
            <p>i am {props.age} years old</p>
            <p>{props.children}</p>
        </div>
        
         )
}
 export default person;

Comment: it's a hell to read such shared code, respect others

Comment: I had the same problem too from Maximilian React course.

Comment: The component name & its export name should be App
Replace
1. const app --> const App
2. export default app --> export default App;

Answer (score 634):

Try to capitalize 'app' like

```
const App = props => {...}

export default App;
```

In React, components need to be capitalized, and custom hooks need to start with `use`.

Comment: This is some hard to find bug in an app, I think another comment should be added to the error message to point out this posibility.

Comment: The reason for this being that in the [Rules of Hooks ESLint plugin](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/c11015ff4f610ac2924d1fc6d569a17657a404fd/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks/src/RulesOfHooks.js), there is a check to see if a component or function name is valid: `Checks if the node is a React component name. React component names must
always start with a non-lowercase letter.`.

Comment: capitalizing A in App works for me... but not i am thinking why max did not get this error in udemy course ?

Comment: Same question " why max did not get any error ? I changed " app" to "App" and now it worked for me!

Comment: Thanks, The naming was the issue which I was not checking.

Answer (score 87):

I feel like we are doing the same course in Udemy.

If so, just capitalize the

`const app`

To

`const App`

Do as well as for the

```
export default app
```

To

```
export default App
```

It works well for me.

Comment: Yep I think that makes 3 of us doing the same course. Why is it it's case sensitive?

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. By default, "main component" name MUST be capitalized.

Also remember to import your components with capitalized names. 

WRONG: import compo from './Compo';

RIGHT: import Compo from './Compo';

As react recognizes capitalized JSX tags as react components .

Comment: why is it case senstive tho?

Answer (score 58):

As far as I know a linter is included into the this package. And it requires you componend should begin from Capital character.
Please check it.

However as for me it's sad.

Comment: Thanks for saving my time.

Answer (score 40):

Use first letter capital in the function name.

```
function App(){}
```

Comment: "First of all, you need to uppercase the FirstLetter of your components, in your case app should be App and person should be Person."

Someone already wrote it...

Comment: This has been answered and this should be marked as the answer. Simple solution explained right.

Answer (score 25):

React components (both functional as well as class) must begin with a capital letter. Like

```
const App=(props)=><div>Hey</div>

class App extends React.Component{
   render(){
     return <div>Hey</div>
   }
}
```

React identifies user-defined components by following this semantic. React's JSX transpiles to React.createElement function which returns an object representation of the dom node. The type property of this object tells whether it is a user-defined component or a dom element like div. Therefore it is important to follow this semantics

Since useState hook can only be used inside the functional component(or a custom hook) this is the reason why you are getting the error because react is not able to identify it as a user-defined component in the first place.

useState can also be used inside the custom hooks which is used for the reusability and the abstraction of logic. So according to the rules of hooks, the name of a custom hook must begin with a "use" prefix and must be in a camelCase

Comment: Yep worked for me for the react-complete-guide project

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks. The issue was that the function name is starting with small latter

Answer (score 20):

Use const App instead of const app

Answer (score 16):

Just try to capitalize your App name

```
const App = props => {...}

export default App;
```

Comment: do you mean document title?

Comment: Its Working, Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You are getting this error: "React Hook "useState" is called in function "App" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function"

Solution: You basically need to Capitalize the function.

For example:

```js
const Helper =()=>{}

function Helper2(){}
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue. turns out that Capitalizing the "A" in "App" was the issue.
Also, if you do export: `export default App;` make sure you export the same name "App" as well.

Answer (score 12):

the First character of your function should be an Uppercase

Comment: Wow, I always forget that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

Components should start with capital letters. Also remember to change the first letter in the line to export!

Comment: Your question doesn't seem like an answer. After reach 50 rep you will be able to comment on questions. If you answer **is** an answer, try improving it. Why components should start with capital letters, for example? Also, other answers have already said that, are you giving anything new?

Answer (score 9):

function name must start with a capital letter

For ex:

```
const App = props => {

}
```

not const app

Answer (score 7):

Do you have the right import ?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

Answer (score 6):

React components names should be **capitalized** and custom hooks functions should start with the **use** keyword to identify as a react hook function.

So, capitalize your **app** components to **App**

Answer (score 6):

**your code**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'; 
import './App.css'; 
import Person from './Person/Person'; 

const app = props => { 
    const [personState, setPersonSate] = useState({ person:[ {name:'bishnu',age:'32'}, {name:'rasmi',age:'27'}, {name:'fretbox',age:'4'} ], }); 
    return (
        <div className="App"> 
            <h2>This is react</h2> 
            <Person name={personState.person[1].name} age="27"></Person>
            <Person name={personState.person[2].name} age="4"></Person> 
        </div> ); 
    };
    export default app;
```

**change it by making the function name capital, like this**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'; 
import './App.css'; 
import Person from './Person/Person'; 

const App = props => { 
    const [personState, setPersonSate] = useState({ person:[ {name:'bishnu',age:'32'}, {name:'rasmi',age:'27'}, {name:'fretbox',age:'4'} ], }); 
    return (
        <div className="App"> 
            <h2>This is react</h2> 
            <Person name={personState.person[1].name} age="27"></Person>
            <Person name={personState.person[2].name} age="4"></Person> 
        </div> ); 
    };
    export default App;
```

it will work Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, but not with the App. I had a custom class but used a lowercase letter to start the function name and also received the error.

Changed the first letter of the function name and the export line to CamelCase and error gone.

in my case the end result was something like:

```
function Document() {
....
}
export default Document;
```

this solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

In JSX, the lower-case tag name is considered as html native component.
In order to react recognise the function as React component, need to Capitalized the name.

```
Capitalized types indicate that the JSX tag is referring to a React component. These tags get compiled into a direct reference to the named variable, so if you use the JSX <Foo /> expression, Foo must be in scope.
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple, correct "app" and write "App" with the first character in uppercase.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (Upvoted). please put some code and answer to the questions.

Answer (score 3):

Replace this

```
export default app;
```

with this

```
export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

Make function name capital. This works for me.

```
export default function App() { }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
React Hook "useState" is called in function "App" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function"
```

For the following error , capitalize the component first letter like, and also the export also.

```
const App  = props => {
...}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

Capitalize the app to App will surely work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change 'app' name to 'App'

```
const App = props => {   
  ...
};  
export default App;`
```

Answer (score 2):

**User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized**. In your case you have used `const app = props => { }`. In "app", 'a' is in lower case, you must try out it to use '**App**'

1. When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like `<div>` or `<span>` and results in a string '**div**' or '**span**' passed to `React.createElement`. Types that start with a capital letter like `<Foo />` compile to `React.createElement(Foo)` and correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.
2. **React** recommend naming components with a **capital letter**. If you do have a component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

For more details you can check Official Document
[Click Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 1):

The solution, as Yuki already pointed, is to capitalize the component name. It's important to note that not only the "default" App component needs to be capitalized, but all components:

```
const Person = () => {return ...};

export default Person;
```

This is due to eslint-plugin-react-hooks package, specifically [isComponentName()](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/c11015ff4f610ac2924d1fc6d569a17657a404fd/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks/src/RulesOfHooks.js#L49) function inside RulesOfHooks.js script.

Official explanation [from Hooks FAQs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-exactly-do-the-lint-rules-enforce):

> We provide an ESLint plugin that enforces rules of Hooks to avoid bugs. It assumes that any function starting with ”use” and a capital letter right after it is a Hook. We recognize this heuristic isn’t perfect and there may be some false positives, but without an ecosystem-wide convention there is just no way to make Hooks work well — and longer names will discourage people from either adopting Hooks or following the convention.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to uppercase the FirstLetter of your components, in your case **app** should be **App** and **person** should be **Person**.

I tried to copy your code in the hope of finding the issue. Since you did not share how you call the **App** component, I can only see 1 way to result this to an issue.

This is the link in CodeSandbox: [Invalid hook call](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-cookies-hrms5).

Why? Because of the code below which is wrong:

```
ReactDOM.render(App(), rootElement);
```

It should have been:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

For more info, you should read [Rule of Hooks - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever working with a React functional component, always keep the first letter of the name of the component in Uppercase in order to avoid these React Hooks errors.

In your case, you have named the component `app`, which should be changed to `App`, as I said above, to avoid the React Hook error.

Answer (score 1):

Use Capital letter for defining functional component name/ React hooks custom components. "const 'app' should be const 'App'.

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person';

const App = props => {
  const [personState, setPersonState] = useState({
    persons : [
          {name: 'a', age: '1'},
          {name: 'b', age: '2'},
          {name: 'c', age: '3'}
    ]
  });

    return (
      <div>
     <Person name = {personState.persons[0].name} age={personState.persons[0].age}> First </Person>
     <Person name = {personState.persons[1].name} age={personState.persons[1].age}> Second </Person>
     <Person name = {personState.persons[2].name} age={personState.persons[2].age}> Third </Person>    
    );
};
export default App;
```

Person.js

```
import React from 'react';

const person = (props) => {
return (
        <div>
<p> My name is {props.name} and my age is {props.age}</p>
<p> My name is {props.name} and my age is {props.age} and {props.children}</p>
<p>{props.children}</p>
        </div>
)
};
```

[ReactHooks] [useState] [ReactJs]

Answer (score 0):

Step-1:
Change the file name src/App.js to src/app.js

Step-2:
Click on "Yes" for "Update imports for app.js".

Step-3:
Restart the server again.

Answer (score 0):

```
        import React, { useState } from "react"

    const inputTextValue = ({ initialValue }) => {
        const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
        return {
            value,
            onChange: (e) => { setValue(e.target.value) }
        };
    };

    export default () => {
        const textValue = inputTextValue("");
        return (<>
            <input {...textValue} />
        </>
        );
    }

/*"Solution I Tired Changed Name of Funtion in Captial "*/

    import React, { useState } from "react"

const InputTextValue = ({ initialValue }) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
    return {
        value,
        onChange: (e) => { setValue(e.target.value) }
    };
};

export default () => {
    const textValue = InputTextValue("");
    return (<>
        <input {...textValue} />
    </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for answer of this question all above stated solution work fine but still i will provide the running/correct code below (edited)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person'

  const App = props => {
    const [personsState, setPersonsState ] = useState({
      persons:[
        {name: 'Ram', age: 20},
        {name: 'Rahul', age: 24},
        {name: 'Ramesh', age: 25}
      ],
      otherState: 'Some Other value' 
    });

    const switchNameHandler = () => {
      //console.log('Click is working');
      //Dont Do THIS: this.state.persons[0].name = 'singh';
      setPersonsState({
        persons:[
        {name: 'Ram',age: 20},
        {name: 'Raj', age: 24},
        {name: 'yts', age: 30} 
      ]
    });
    };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Nice two one three  Hello i am a noob react developer</h1>
        <button onClick={switchNameHandler}>Switch Name</button>
        <Person name={personsState.persons[0].name} age={personsState.persons[0].age} />
        <Person name={personsState.persons[1].name} age={personsState.persons[1].age}> My hobbies are Gaming</Person>
        <Person name={personsState.persons[2].name} age={personsState.persons[2].age} />
      </div>
    ); 
    // return React.createElement('div',{className:'App'}, React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hi learning the basics of react'));
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have added the `useEffect` that depends on the condition before the one with no condition

EX:

```
useEffect(() => {
  _anyFunction();
}, []);
    
useEffect(()=> {
  anyCode....
}, [response]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you take same course that I have because you are using exactly the same variables name in this ,actually you are missing a little thing here that is you change the name of your app with a lower case

```
export default app
```

there is a little mistake that is also change the name in index.js you change the name here in the App.js but forgot to change it in index.js you are still importing it like this

```
import App from './App.js'
```

so you also had to change the name there

Answer (score 0):

just as best practice, try to destructure the props element before using it in the Person component. Also use functional components instead of consts. (It is less confusing and you can be done with things faster )

```
function ({person}) {
  const name={person.name}
  return (
    <h2>{name}</h2>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In the app function you have incorrectly spelled the word `setpersonSate`, missing the letter `t`, thus it should be `setpersonState`.

**Error**:

```
const app = props => { 
    const [personState, setPersonSate] = useState({....
```

**Solution**:

```
const app = props => { 
        const [personState, setPersonState] = useState({....
```

Answer (score -5):

Do not use arrow function to create functional components.

Do as one of the examples below:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  const [states, setStates] = React.useState({ value: '' });

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={states.value}
      onChange={(event) => setStates({ value: event.target.value })}
    />
  );
}
```

Or

```
//IMPORTANT: Repeat the function name

const MyComponent = function MyComponent(props) { 
  const [states, setStates] = React.useState({ value: '' });

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={states.value}
      onChange={(event) => setStates({ value: event.target.value })}
    />
  );
};
```

If you have problems with `"ref"` (probably in loops), the solution is to use `forwardRef()`:

```
// IMPORTANT: Repeat the function name
// Add the "ref" argument to the function, in case you need to use it.

const MyComponent = React.forwardRef( function MyComponent(props, ref) {
  const [states, setStates] = React.useState({ value: '' });

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={states.value}
      onChange={(event) => setStates({ value: event.target.value })}
    />
  );
});
```

Comment: Can you explain more, why "Do not use arrow function to create functional components." ? - Thanks

Comment: To avoid problems with useState () in some situations, such as in this case: https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-error-f452s