# UseState Error when utilizing React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using hooks but I get this error

Line 25:  React Hook "React.useState" is called in function "contact" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 26:  React Hook "React.useState" is called in function "contact" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 27:  React Hook "React.useState" is called in function "contact" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

```
export default function contact() {

 const [messageInput, setMessageInput] = React.useState("");
 const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
 const [name, setName] = React.useState("");

 const enables =
   messageInput.length > 0 &&
   email.length > 0 &&
   name.length > 0;


 return (

<div className="App">
```

I have done a similar project before and I am using my old project as a reference. This didn't happened in my old project.

Comment: PascalCase for component names

Comment: I always forget, Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The rules-of-hooks lint rule uses naming conventions to infer what functions are for. Functions starting with `use` are assumed to be hooks. Functions starting with a capital letter are assumed to be components. `contact` is neither. Change it to `Contact`.

Answer (score 0):

Component name should be capitalized, try Changing **contact** to **Contact** .
You can find detailed conversation related to this issue here: [React Hook "useState" is called in function "app" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846641/react-hook-usestate-is-called-in-function-app-which-is-neither-a-react-funct)