# React Hook "useState" is called in function "test" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use React useState hook in my functional component but I am getting this error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/Person/Person.js
  Line 5:43:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "person" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

Here is the code for the same:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { tsPropertySignature, directive } from '@babel/types';

const person =props =>{
    const [initState,stateChangeFunction]=useState({name:'akie@123'})
return <p>I am from the {}</p>   
}
 export default person;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846641/react-hook-usestate-is-called-in-function-app-which-is-neither-a-react-funct

Comment: If you use   `useState`   your function name should start with capital letter, if there is no     `useState`  then capital/small letter both will work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hook "useState" is called in function "app" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846641/react-hook-usestate-is-called-in-function-app-which-is-neither-a-react-funct)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- React recognize capitalized function name as a react function component, in your case

`function Person () {}`

- Furthermore, React only recognize function name starting with '`use`' as a custom hook, like

`function usePeople() {}`

- Hooks **ONLY** available in a function component or a custom hook

Comment: This was annoying to debug! Thought I was going crazy. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thank you!! They need to be more specific about this

Answer (score 12):

Your Component name should be capitalise it should look like this :-

```js
const Person = () => {
 // .......
 }

 export default Person;
```