# can anyone help me with this react error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

***ERROR***

Line 6:44:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "app" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Please show the code that generates the error.

Comment: are you calling App as a function App() or as a component <App /> ?

Comment: const [personsState, setPersonsState ] = useState({
    persons: [
      {name: 'Mann', age: '20'},
      {name: 'Mab', age: '25'},
      {name: 'Bar', age: '43'}
    ] 
  });

Comment: @DanielPérez yes

Comment: @Mab can you please show the full file that generates the error (you can update your question to show it.)

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer can you get something wrong out of it

Comment: @Mab you should use PascalCase for components, without you sharing the code I can't tell for sure but if you are using function app() you should use function App()

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer friend as i'm new over here,can u help me out.actually the code is long and over here comment has limit for letters which is lesser then my code.so i'm un able to add comment over here

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer is here any option for file sharing??

Comment: @DanielPérez i'll try that!!

Comment: @DanielPérez That worked my Friend Thankyou so much !!!!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hook "useState" is called in function "app" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846641/react-hook-usestate-is-called-in-function-app-which-is-neither-a-react-funct)

Comment: @Mab you can add the code to the original question by editing the question.

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer i have actually tried it but as there was error in the code so it was not allowing wrong code !!!!

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer but now as it's solved i'll try to it

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer I tried it but still there are some problems . it is actually not allowing mine code in the ask quetion section

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this one with typescript, changing the component name to start with capital letter fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the useState hook and not importing React and the useState Hook in your function

```
import React,{useState} from "react";

//use a capital letter in the begging of your component name
export const YourComponent = () =>{
   //Now you can use the useState hook here in a react functional component
   const [personsState, setPersonsState ] = useState({ persons: [ 
        {name: 'Mann', age:'20'}, 
        {name: 'Mab', age: '25'}, 
        {name: 'Bar', age: '43'} 
      ] })

   return(
     <div>
       //you can use personsState here now
     </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create-react-app version 3+

& newer React versions require components

containing React Hooks to be capitalized (PascalCase).

Meaning:  The component name & its export (name).

Change the two (names) app to App.