# Create controlled input with drag&drop in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I am trying to create a component to upload a single image, show its preview and delete option. Also, it is important for me to be able to upload from the backend base64 encoded URL into field `value`. This is what I have at the moment. I pass `value` from the application state into component props, I've implemented `onChange` handler so it writes the URL to the state and `deleteImage` just deletes the URL from state.

```js
const ImageInput = ({ value, onChange, deleteImage }) => (
    <div>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={onChange}/>
        { value &&
        (<div>
           <img src={value} alt="" width="50"/>
           <span onClick={deleteImage}>&#10060;</span>
         </div>)
        }
    </div>
);
```

But now I want to replace the usual input with a drag & drop zone and looking for the easiest way to do this. I would be grateful for any help.

**Updated.**
I've chosen to use the library `react-dnd`, but I don't fully understand how to use it here. So I have to do something like that first?

```js
import {DndProvider} from "react-dnd";
import {HTML5Backend} from "react-dnd-html5-backend";

const ImageInput = ({ value, onChange, deleteImage }) => (
    <div>
        <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
           <myDropTarget/>
        </DndProvider>
        { value &&
        (<div>
           <img src={value} alt="" width="50"/>
           <span onClick={deleteImage}>&#10060;</span>
         </div>)
        }
    </div>
);
```

And then just create such a component.

```js
import React from "react";
import { useDrop } from 'react-dnd'


export function myDropTarget(props) {
    const [collectedProps, drop] = useDrop({
        accept
    })

    return <div ref={drop}>Drop Target</div>
}
```

But it doesn't work for me. I get an error: `React Hook "useDrop" is called in function "myDropTarget" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function`

Comment: Probably this: https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/overview

Comment: @MattMorgan thanks for the hint, I think it might help me. I updated my question because I don't understand some usage details of this library

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55862839/3084820

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with [react-uploady](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady):

```js
import React from "react";
import Uploady from "@rpldy/uploady";
import UploadDropZone from "@rpldy/upload-drop-zone";
import UploadPreview from "@rpldy/upload-preview";

const firstFileOnlyFilter = (file, index) => index === 0;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Uploady
      destination={{ url: "[upload-url]" }}
      fileFilter={firstFileOnlyFilter}
    >            
        <DropZone>Drag file here</DropZone>
        <br />
        <UploadPreview />
    </Uploady>
  );
}
```

You can see a working example in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-uploady-dnd-with-preview-1x382).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does it have the ability to attach a picture from the backend?

Comment: i dont understand what "attach a picture from the backend" means. please explain

Comment: Can I pass a picture (base64 encoded URL), for example, from the application state to this component to display its preview?

Comment: where does the "base64 encoded URL" come from? is it a URL or the actual image content?

Comment: It's actual image content

Comment: @Helen check out this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-uploady-base64-nwkwo?file=/src/App.js) Uploady can handle base64 uploads just as well.

Comment: It is very cool! I will try to use it to solve my problem.